# Running simple regression in base Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I'm learning Tensorflow 2.0 and I thought that it would be a good idea to implement the most basic simple linear regression in Tensorflow. Unfortunately, I ran into several issues and I was wondering if anyone here might be able to help.

Consider the following set up:

```py
import tensorflow as tf # 2.0.0-alpha0
import numpy as np

x_data = np.random.randn(2000, 1)

w_real = [0.7] # coefficients
b_real = -0.2 # global bias
noise = np.random.randn(1, 2000) * 0.5 # level of noise
y_data = np.matmul(w_real, x_data.T) + b_real + noise
```

Now on with the model definition:

```py
# modelling this data with tensorflow (manually!)
class SimpleRegressionNN(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleRegressionNN, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)


    def call(self, data_input):
        model = self.input_layer(data_input)
        model = self.output_layer(model)
        # open question: how to account for the intercept/bias term?
        # Ideally, we'd want to generate preds as matmult(X,W) + b
        return model

nn_regressor = SimpleRegressionNN()

reg_loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
reg_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1)
metric_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error

# define forward step
@tf.function
def train_step(x_sample, y_sample):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = nn_regressor(x_sample)
    loss = reg_loss(y_sample, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, nn_regressor.trainable_variables) # had to indent this!
  reg_optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, nn_regressor.trainable_variables))  
  metric_accuracy(y_sample, predictions)

#%%
# run the model
for epoch in range(10):
    for x_point, y_point in zip(x_data.T[0], y_data[0]): # batch of 1
        train_step(x_sample=x_point, y_sample=y_point)
    print("MSE: {}".format(metric_accuracy.result()))
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
"""
```

The full error output is here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    611                                                       inputs)) as auto_updater:
--> 612                 outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    613                 auto_updater.set_outputs(outputs)

<ipython-input-5-8464ad8bcf07> in call(self, data_input)
      7     def call(self, data_input):
----> 8         model = self.input_layer(data_input)
      9         model = self.output_layer(model)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_size, name, dtype, sparse, tensor, **kwargs)
    232       sparse=sparse,
--> 233       input_tensor=tensor)
    234   # Return tensor including `_keras_history`.

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name, **kwargs)
     93       if input_shape is not None:
---> 94         batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(input_shape)
     95       else:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __iter__(self)
    448       raise TypeError(
--> 449           "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "
    450           "enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.")

TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-e1bde858b0fc> in <module>()
      3     #train_step(x_sample=x_data.T[0], y_sample=y_data[0])
      4     for x_point, y_point in zip(x_data.T[0], y_data[0]):
----> 5         train_step(x_sample=x_point, y_sample=y_point)
      6     print("MSE: {}".format(metric_accuracy.result()))
      7 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    416       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    417       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 418       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    419       if self._created_variables:
    420         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1285   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1286     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
-> 1287     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1288     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1289 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   1609           relaxed_arg_shapes)
   1610       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
-> 1611           args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   1612       self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function
   1613 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   1510             arg_names=arg_names,
   1511             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 1512             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   1513         self._function_attributes)
   1514 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    692                                           converted_func)
    693 
--> 694       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    695 
    696       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, IndexedSlices,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    315         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    316         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 317         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    318     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    319 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    684                   optional_features=autograph_options,
    685                   force_conversion=True,
--> 686               ), args, kwargs)
    687 
    688         # Wrapping around a decorator allows checks like tf_inspect.getargspec

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, owner, options, args, kwargs)
    390     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs)
    391 
--> 392   result = converted_f(*effective_args, **kwargs)
    393 
    394   # The converted function's closure is simply inserted into the function's

/var/folders/8_/pl9fgq297ld3b7kgy5tmvf700000gn/T/tmpluzodr7d.py in tf__train_step(x_sample, y_sample)
      2 def tf__train_step(x_sample, y_sample):
      3   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
----> 4     predictions = ag__.converted_call(nn_regressor, None, ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, verbose=0, strip_decorators=(tf.function, defun, ag__.convert, ag__.do_not_convert, ag__.converted_call), force_conversion=False, optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True), (x_sample,), {})
      5     loss = ag__.converted_call(reg_loss, None, ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, verbose=0, strip_decorators=(tf.function, defun_1, ag__.convert, ag__.do_not_convert, ag__.converted_call), force_conversion=False, optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True), (y_sample, predictions), {})
      6     gradients = ag__.converted_call('gradient', tape, ag__.ConversionOptions(recursive=True, verbose=0, strip_decorators=(tf.function, defun_2, ag__.convert, ag__.do_not_convert, ag__.converted_call), force_conversion=False, optional_features=(), internal_convert_user_code=True), (loss, nn_regressor.trainable_variables), {})

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, owner, options, args, kwargs)
    265 
    266   if not options.force_conversion and conversion.is_whitelisted_for_graph(f):
--> 267     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs)
    268 
    269   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs)
    186     return f.__self__.call(args, kwargs)
    187 
--> 188   return f(*args, **kwargs)
    189 
    190 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    623                                   'dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class '
    624                                   'constructor.\nEncountered error:\n"""\n' +
--> 625                                   exception_str + '\n"""')
    626               raise
    627           else:

TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
"""
```

The trouble is, 2.0 is set to eager execution by default!

In addition to this problem, I have a few extra questions:

1. What would be the best way to account for the intercept term here?
2. Is the general approach reasonable or am I doing anything odd here? (ignoring the batch size and the fact that I have to validation data, this is just a toy example)

Many thanks!

Comment: `(1)` `tf.keras.layers.Dense()` adds intercept by default. What is the exact line the error points?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm afraid locating the source of the error isn't that straightforward. I've included the entire error output, hope it helps. I just tried running the `train_step` function by itself, and it gave me the same error, that's as much as I can narrow it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have following remarks:

- You don't need `Input` layer in your `SimpleRegression` model. Also, don't call the tensor output of the layer by "`model`" name (as you do in the `call()` method). This is really confusing.
- You don't pass correct shapes to your `train_step` function. It expects to receive `(n_samples, input_dim)` while you passing (`input_dim`, ).
- Remember, in `tensorflow` first dimension of a tensor is always the batch size (i.e. number of samples). Use it always like that, without transposing.
- Why do you call `metric_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error` accuracy? You have a regression problem, there's no such thing as accuracy in regression. Also, why do you define twice and compute twice `mse`?
- If you convert your data using `tf.convert_to_tensor()` the execution will be faster.
- Function `train_step()` performs forward and backward passes and not just a forward pass.
- Use small datasets for toy examples (2-10 samples, not 2000), especially if you don't know whether or not your code works!
- Your function `train_step()` doesn't return anything, how do you expect to print the value of the `mse` loss.

This is a corrected version of your code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf # 2.0.0-alpha0
import numpy as np

x_data = np.random.randn(5, 2)

w_real = 0.7 # coefficients
b_real = -0.2 # global bias
noise = np.random.randn(5, 2) * 0.01 # level of noise
y_data = w_real * x_data + b_real + noise

class SimpleRegressionNN(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleRegressionNN, self).__init__()

        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2, ))

    def call(self, data_input):
        result = self.output_layer(data_input)
        return result

reg_loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
reg_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1)

nn_regressor = SimpleRegressionNN()

@tf.function
def train_step(x_sample, y_sample):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = nn_regressor(x_sample)
        loss = reg_loss(y_sample, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, nn_regressor.trainable_variables) # had to indent this!
    reg_optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, nn_regressor.trainable_variables))  

    return loss

for x_point, y_point in zip(x_data, y_data): # batch of 1
    x_point, y_point = tf.convert_to_tensor([x_point]), tf.convert_to_tensor([y_point])
    mse = train_step(x_sample=x_point, y_sample=y_point)
    print("MSE: {}".format(mse.numpy()))
```

Comment: Vlad, thank you so much! I was following a few examples that I could find online (but there isn't much on TF 2.0) which is why there were a few oddities in my code. Your example makes perfect sense, thank you again!

Comment: Glad it helped. I've corrected small inaccuracy in my code. It is better to compute and apply gradients outside the `GradientTape` context (If you not intend to compute second derivatives). It is not a mistake but if you do it within `GradientTape` context it will record these operations to the buffer which adds unnecessary overhead.