# TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using `TensorFlow 2.0.0` and `tf.keras` to create a model network that takes in n inputs, `[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,...xn]`, and computes `f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,...xn)`.

I have defined my model below as:

```
def custom_func(vec):   # Test function specifically for a 2-D input
        [x,y] = vec
        x1 = tf.math.atanh(x)
        y1 = tf.math.atanh(y)
        return tf.math.exp(-x1**2 + -y1**2)*(x1**2 + y1**2)

ndim = 2     #Input is 2-D for a sample case
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='ones',bias_initializer='zeros',
                    activation=custom_func, input_shape=(ndim,)))

print(model2.predict(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])))
```

On running the following code-block I get the error:

```
TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
"""
```

What is possibly causing this error? And how do I fix this? Any help/suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734820/running-simple-regression-in-base-tensorflow-2-0

Comment: `vec` is a `tf.Tensor` and you cannot do `[x, y] = vec` which raises the error. What do you want to do here?

Answer (score 3):

even though I'm not clear that what you wanted to do, I tried it out in this way for you. Hope it may help you. as we use eager execution it allows to that evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs: operations return concrete values instead of constructing a computational graph to run later.m[ore info](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) .I used keras Activation  for custom activation function and dynamic=True for the Dense layer.it works up to this point

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Activation
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects

@tf.function
def custom_activation(vec):   # Test function specifically for a 2-D input
  [x,y] = vec
  x1 = tf.math.atanh(x)
  y1 = tf.math.atanh(y)
  return tf.math.exp(-x1**2 + -y1**2)*(x1**2 + y1**2)



ndim = 2     #Input is 2-D for a sample case


mnist_model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='ones',bias_initializer='zeros',activation=Activation('custom_activation'), input_shape=(ndim,),dynamic=True)])

@tf.function
def output():
  print(mnist_model(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])))


output()
```

output result:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Tensor("sequential/dense/Placeholder:0", shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @tf.function before the function defination.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: Check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628640/typeerror-you-are-attempting-to-use-python-control-flow-in-a-layer-that-was-not